# Customize LINQ data mapping

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a set of entities to be stored in a sql database. Each entity is stored into a single table. Some entity fields are stored into columns (so we can query with them) but whole entity instance is serialized as JSON on a special column named 'JsonContent'.

I'd like to be able to use LINQ with these entities. Queries should support two modes:

1. Thin objects: queried items only include column fields
2. Fat objects: queried items contains both columns and 'JsonContent' data.

How do I accomplish that?

I wrote a class with the following class:

```
class Store<TEntity> {
     public IList<TEntity> Select(
         Expression<Func<TProto, bool>> where, bool fat) {...}
}
```

I'm translating `where` to SQL. That's reinventing the wheel. How do I get rid of that?

Answer (score 0):

You should just let entity Framework generate the model from your DB, it will contain only 1 set (what you call your fat item) that you can query (of course you can't query within the json but not much you can do about that).

Then you could create a plain C# object you'd call thinobject, make it contain all the properties minus the json, and add an extension method you'd name ToThinObject that takes an IQueryable and returns an IQueryable which would just retun a select on the original iqueryable

That way you can do whatever you want in a query that doesn't materialize (no foreach/Tolist etc)

```
var q = context.MyTable
     .Where(bla)
     .Take(bla)
     .etc etc etc


 var Everything = q.ToList() // retrieves everything including JSON
 var NotEverything = q.ToThinObject().ToList() // contains everything except the JSON, JSON is never retrieved from the database
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid use of EF. Mainly because classes will depend on the DB. My entities are already generated from an IDL. I'd have to make sure that DB schema matches the IDL (I only do that during runtime via ALTER TABLE calls).

Comment: I was looking for a solution that uses reflection, like using Table and Column attributes. But I can't use those because classes are generated by a third party tool.

Comment: Well you mentioned not reinventing the Wheel, if not using EF you're going to reinvent pretty much everything. What you can do is use EF code first using your already generated entities, since you only have 1 table it would work pretty much regardless of how they are done and as a bonus you can get rid of your alter table and let entity Framework auto migrations modify your DB on change

Comment: Based on some research, I think I want to implement a MappingSource class (like XmlMappingSource) and use DataContext.

Comment: I still don't see why you'd want to do anything that low level, the solution i mentioned represents 0 lines of code, 3 click in visual studio and works perfectly as is with your solution even with what you added in your comments, if you have other restrictions could you please update your question and include more code / all of your functional needs? It's hard to help you if you don't state everything

Comment: I made it very clear: my classes are generated from an IDL. DB is NOT the primary source. I can't afford to manually keep IDL and DB in sync in order to use VS. It is error prone and breaks automation. Going with dynamic mapping source, I don't need to use VS or any DB. It is all done in runtime.

Comment: And, as i said, you can use the classes GENERATED BY YOUR IDL with entity Framework! You don't need to keep anything in sync manually and it still is all done at runtime, without you even having to handle what you currently do at runtime (EF does it for you), you simply point EF to your classes (the one created by your IDL) and voila you're done, DB does not have to be the primary source at all, your code can be, odds are you could even get rid of the IDL and simply use EF code first but that's beyond the point, in the scenario you describe, with your generated classes, you can use EF AS IS